# Merge multiple tables (identical headers) within a text file

Tags: r, linux, dataframe

Say I have more than 200 files - each structured as depicted below:

```
# Peptide length 11
# Rank Threshold for Strong binding peptides   0.500
# Rank Threshold for Weak binding peptides   2.000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  pos          HLA      peptide         Core Offset  I_pos  I_len  D_pos  D_len        iCore        Identity 1-log50k(aff) Affinity(nM)    %Rank  BindLevel
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0    HLA-B4402  GSHDLGIILQK    GSHDLGIIL      0      0      0      0      0    GSHDLGIIL NM_000094_3_COL         0.015     42580.79    90.00
    1    HLA-B4402  SHDLGIILQKI    SLGIILQKI      0      0      0      1      2  SHDLGIILQKI NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38731.55    65.00
    2    HLA-B4402  HDLGIILQKIR    HDLIILQKI      0      0      0      3      1   HDLGIILQKI NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38400.24    65.00
    3    HLA-B4402  DLGIILQKIRD    DLGIILQKI      0      0      0      0      0    DLGIILQKI NM_000094_3_COL         0.011     44267.78    95.00
    4    HLA-B4402  LGIILQKIRDM    LGIILQRDM      0      0      0      6      2  LGIILQKIRDM NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38411.46    65.00
    5    HLA-B4402  GIILQKIRDMP    GIILQIRDM      0      0      0      5      1   GIILQKIRDM NM_000094_3_COL         0.017     41463.75    80.00
    6    HLA-B4402  IILQKIRDMPY    IILQKIRDY      0      0      0      8      2  IILQKIRDMPY NM_000094_3_COL         0.025     38152.18    65.00
    7    HLA-B4402  ILQKIRDMPYM    ILQKIRMPY      0      0      0      6      1   ILQKIRDMPY NM_000094_3_COL         0.025     37993.98    60.00
    8    HLA-B4402  LQKIRDMPYMD    QKIRDMPYM      1      0      0      0      0    QKIRDMPYM NM_000094_3_COL         0.015     42595.54    90.00
    9    HLA-B4402  QKIRDMPYMDP    QKIRDMPYM      0      0      0      0      0    QKIRDMPYM NM_000094_3_COL         0.017     41645.82    85.00
   10    HLA-B4402  KIRDMPYMDPS    KDMPYMDPS      0      0      0      1      2  KIRDMPYMDPS NM_000094_3_COL         0.023     39039.53    70.00
   11    HLA-B4402  IRDMPYMDPSX    RDMPYMPSX      1      0      0      6      1   RDMPYMDPSX NM_000094_3_COL         0.036     33871.57    41.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Protein NM_000094_3_COL. Allele HLA-B4402. Number of high binders 0. Number of weak binders 0. Number of peptides 12

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rank Threshold for Strong binding peptides   0.500
# Rank Threshold for Weak binding peptides   2.000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  pos          HLA      peptide         Core Offset  I_pos  I_len  D_pos  D_len        iCore        Identity 1-log50k(aff) Affinity(nM)    %Rank  BindLevel
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0    HLA-B4402  PVTGYKVQYTS    TGYKVQYTS      2      0      0      0      0    TGYKVQYTS NM_000094_3_COL         0.011     44190.25    95.00
    1    HLA-B4402  VTGYKVQYTSL    VTGYQYTSL      0      0      0      4      2  VTGYKVQYTSL NM_000094_3_COL         0.020     40061.36    75.00
    2    HLA-B4402  TGYKVQYTSLT    TGYKVYTSL      0      0      0      5      1   TGYKVQYTSL NM_000094_3_COL         0.020     40487.08    75.00
    3    HLA-B4402  GYKVQYTSLTG    YVQYTSLTG      1      0      0      1      1   YKVQYTSLTG NM_000094_3_COL         0.017     41521.20    80.00
    4    HLA-B4402  YKVQYTSLTGL    YQYTSLTGL      0      0      0      1      2  YKVQYTSLTGL NM_000094_3_COL         0.031     35710.76    49.00
    5    HLA-B4402  KVQYTSLTGLG    KVQYTSLTL      0      0      0      8      1   KVQYTSLTGL NM_000094_3_COL         0.029     36392.20    55.00
    6    HLA-B4402  VQYTSLTGLGQ    VQYTSLTGL      0      0      0      0      0    VQYTSLTGL NM_000094_3_COL         0.016     42180.50    85.00
    7    HLA-B4402  QYTSLTGLGQP    QYTSLTGLG      0      0      0      0      0    QYTSLTGLG NM_000094_3_COL         0.011     44293.17    95.00
    8    HLA-B4402  YTSLTGLGQPL    YTSLLGQPL      0      0      0      4      2  YTSLTGLGQPL NM_000094_3_COL         0.034     34547.04    44.00
    9    HLA-B4402  TSLTGLGQPLP    SLTGLGQPL      1      0      0      0      0    SLTGLGQPL NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38475.10    65.00
   10    HLA-B4402  SLTGLGQPLPS    SLTGLGQPL      0      0      0      0      0    SLTGLGQPL NM_000094_3_COL         0.026     37575.76    60.00
   11    HLA-B4402  LTGLGQPLPSX    LLGQPLPSX      0      0      0      1      2  LTGLGQPLPSX NM_000094_3_COL         0.014     42874.84    90.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Protein NM_000094_3_COL. Allele HLA-B4402. Number of high binders 0. Number of weak binders 0. Number of peptides 12

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rank Threshold for Strong binding peptides   0.500
# Rank Threshold for Weak binding peptides   2.000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  pos          HLA      peptide         Core Offset  I_pos  I_len  D_pos  D_len        iCore        Identity 1-log50k(aff) Affinity(nM)    %Rank  BindLevel
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0    HLA-B4402  FLRLLDLAQEE    RLLDLAQEE      2      0      0      0      0    RLLDLAQEE NM_000106_5_CYP         0.014     42841.45    90.00
    1    HLA-B4402  LRLLDLAQEEL    RLLDLAQEL      1      0      0      7      1   RLLDLAQEEL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.029     36648.25    55.00
    2    HLA-B4402  RLLDLAQEELK    RLLDLAQEL      0      0      0      7      1   RLLDLAQEEL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.029     36350.87    55.00
    3    HLA-B4402  LLDLAQEELKE    LLDLAQEEL      0      0      0      0      0    LLDLAQEEL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.013     43487.79    95.00
    4    HLA-B4402  LDLAQEELKEE    LDQEELKEE      0      0      0      2      2  LDLAQEELKEE NM_000106_5_CYP         0.008     45629.40    99.00
    5    HLA-B4402  DLAQEELKEES    AQEELKEES      2      0      0      0      0    AQEELKEES NM_000106_5_CYP         0.009     45287.57    99.00
    6    HLA-B4402  LAQEELKEESG    AEELKEESG      1      0      0      1      1   AQEELKEESG NM_000106_5_CYP         0.013     43568.32    95.00
    7    HLA-B4402  AQEELKEESGF    AELKEESGF      0      0      0      1      2  AQEELKEESGF NM_000106_5_CYP         0.231      4113.65     2.50
    8    HLA-B4402  QEELKEESGFL    QELKEESGF      0      0      0      1      1   QEELKEESGF NM_000106_5_CYP         0.123     13202.71     6.00
    9    HLA-B4402  EELKEESGFLR    EELKEESGF      0      0      0      0      0    EELKEESGF NM_000106_5_CYP         0.076     21904.46    13.00
   10    HLA-B4402  ELKEESGFLRE    ELKEESGFL      0      0      0      0      0    ELKEESGFL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.030     36301.74    55.00
   11    HLA-B4402  LKEESGFLREX    KEESFLREX      1      0      0      4      1   KEESGFLREX NM_000106_5_CYP         0.060     26205.35    19.00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As it can be seen, each file is basically a combination of tables (with identical headers) with text in between them. I would like to keep only the tables - and if possible get rid of those dashed lines, keeping only the data (and header) separated by `\t` for each line.

The optimal result would be like this:

```
pos          HLA      peptide         Core Offset  I_pos  I_len  D_pos  D_len        iCore        Identity 1-log50k(aff) Affinity(nM)    %Rank  BindLevel
    0    HLA-B4402  GSHDLGIILQK    GSHDLGIIL      0      0      0      0      0    GSHDLGIIL NM_000094_3_COL         0.015     42580.79    90.00
    1    HLA-B4402  SHDLGIILQKI    SLGIILQKI      0      0      0      1      2  SHDLGIILQKI NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38731.55    65.00
    2    HLA-B4402  HDLGIILQKIR    HDLIILQKI      0      0      0      3      1   HDLGIILQKI NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38400.24    65.00
    3    HLA-B4402  DLGIILQKIRD    DLGIILQKI      0      0      0      0      0    DLGIILQKI NM_000094_3_COL         0.011     44267.78    95.00
    4    HLA-B4402  LGIILQKIRDM    LGIILQRDM      0      0      0      6      2  LGIILQKIRDM NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38411.46    65.00
    5    HLA-B4402  GIILQKIRDMP    GIILQIRDM      0      0      0      5      1   GIILQKIRDM NM_000094_3_COL         0.017     41463.75    80.00
    6    HLA-B4402  IILQKIRDMPY    IILQKIRDY      0      0      0      8      2  IILQKIRDMPY NM_000094_3_COL         0.025     38152.18    65.00
    7    HLA-B4402  ILQKIRDMPYM    ILQKIRMPY      0      0      0      6      1   ILQKIRDMPY NM_000094_3_COL         0.025     37993.98    60.00
    8    HLA-B4402  LQKIRDMPYMD    QKIRDMPYM      1      0      0      0      0    QKIRDMPYM NM_000094_3_COL         0.015     42595.54    90.00
    9    HLA-B4402  QKIRDMPYMDP    QKIRDMPYM      0      0      0      0      0    QKIRDMPYM NM_000094_3_COL         0.017     41645.82    85.00
   10    HLA-B4402  KIRDMPYMDPS    KDMPYMDPS      0      0      0      1      2  KIRDMPYMDPS NM_000094_3_COL         0.023     39039.53    70.00
   11    HLA-B4402  IRDMPYMDPSX    RDMPYMPSX      1      0      0      6      1   RDMPYMDPSX NM_000094_3_COL         0.036     33871.57    41.00
    0    HLA-B4402  PVTGYKVQYTS    TGYKVQYTS      2      0      0      0      0    TGYKVQYTS NM_000094_3_COL         0.011     44190.25    95.00
    1    HLA-B4402  VTGYKVQYTSL    VTGYQYTSL      0      0      0      4      2  VTGYKVQYTSL NM_000094_3_COL         0.020     40061.36    75.00
    2    HLA-B4402  TGYKVQYTSLT    TGYKVYTSL      0      0      0      5      1   TGYKVQYTSL NM_000094_3_COL         0.020     40487.08    75.00
    3    HLA-B4402  GYKVQYTSLTG    YVQYTSLTG      1      0      0      1      1   YKVQYTSLTG NM_000094_3_COL         0.017     41521.20    80.00
    4    HLA-B4402  YKVQYTSLTGL    YQYTSLTGL      0      0      0      1      2  YKVQYTSLTGL NM_000094_3_COL         0.031     35710.76    49.00
    5    HLA-B4402  KVQYTSLTGLG    KVQYTSLTL      0      0      0      8      1   KVQYTSLTGL NM_000094_3_COL         0.029     36392.20    55.00
    6    HLA-B4402  VQYTSLTGLGQ    VQYTSLTGL      0      0      0      0      0    VQYTSLTGL NM_000094_3_COL         0.016     42180.50    85.00
    7    HLA-B4402  QYTSLTGLGQP    QYTSLTGLG      0      0      0      0      0    QYTSLTGLG NM_000094_3_COL         0.011     44293.17    95.00
    8    HLA-B4402  YTSLTGLGQPL    YTSLLGQPL      0      0      0      4      2  YTSLTGLGQPL NM_000094_3_COL         0.034     34547.04    44.00
    9    HLA-B4402  TSLTGLGQPLP    SLTGLGQPL      1      0      0      0      0    SLTGLGQPL NM_000094_3_COL         0.024     38475.10    65.00
   10    HLA-B4402  SLTGLGQPLPS    SLTGLGQPL      0      0      0      0      0    SLTGLGQPL NM_000094_3_COL         0.026     37575.76    60.00
   11    HLA-B4402  LTGLGQPLPSX    LLGQPLPSX      0      0      0      1      2  LTGLGQPLPSX NM_000094_3_COL         0.014     42874.84    90.00
    0    HLA-B4402  FLRLLDLAQEE    RLLDLAQEE      2      0      0      0      0    RLLDLAQEE NM_000106_5_CYP         0.014     42841.45    90.00
    1    HLA-B4402  LRLLDLAQEEL    RLLDLAQEL      1      0      0      7      1   RLLDLAQEEL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.029     36648.25    55.00
    2    HLA-B4402  RLLDLAQEELK    RLLDLAQEL      0      0      0      7      1   RLLDLAQEEL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.029     36350.87    55.00
    3    HLA-B4402  LLDLAQEELKE    LLDLAQEEL      0      0      0      0      0    LLDLAQEEL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.013     43487.79    95.00
    4    HLA-B4402  LDLAQEELKEE    LDQEELKEE      0      0      0      2      2  LDLAQEELKEE NM_000106_5_CYP         0.008     45629.40    99.00
    5    HLA-B4402  DLAQEELKEES    AQEELKEES      2      0      0      0      0    AQEELKEES NM_000106_5_CYP         0.009     45287.57    99.00
    6    HLA-B4402  LAQEELKEESG    AEELKEESG      1      0      0      1      1   AQEELKEESG NM_000106_5_CYP         0.013     43568.32    95.00
    7    HLA-B4402  AQEELKEESGF    AELKEESGF      0      0      0      1      2  AQEELKEESGF NM_000106_5_CYP         0.231      4113.65     2.50
    8    HLA-B4402  QEELKEESGFL    QELKEESGF      0      0      0      1      1   QEELKEESGF NM_000106_5_CYP         0.123     13202.71     6.00
    9    HLA-B4402  EELKEESGFLR    EELKEESGF      0      0      0      0      0    EELKEESGF NM_000106_5_CYP         0.076     21904.46    13.00
   10    HLA-B4402  ELKEESGFLRE    ELKEESGFL      0      0      0      0      0    ELKEESGFL NM_000106_5_CYP         0.030     36301.74    55.00
   11    HLA-B4402  LKEESGFLREX    KEESFLREX      1      0      0      4      1   KEESGFLREX NM_000106_5_CYP         0.060     26205.35    19.00
```

So that's what I am struggling with:

##### 1. How to concatenate all tables within the same file in a single table?

##### 2. Is it possible to concatenate all tables from all files in a single table?

If there is a way to do it in R, it is also fine.

Thanks a lot!

PS: I went through the *Similar questions* section but couldn't find any solution in this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract and parse the data from one file.

I've tried to split the data and add a header but I'm not 100% sure if it's worked properly,

```
library(dplyr)

original_df <-
  as.data.frame(readLines("ProteinData.txt", warn = FALSE))

colnames(original_df) <- c("Column1")

header <- original_df %>% filter(str_detect(Column1, "^\\s+pos"))

header <- unlist(str_split(head(header, 1), "\\s+"))

header <- replace(header, header == "" , "Unused")

parsed_df <- original_df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Column1, "^\\W+\\d")) %>%
  separate(Column1, header, sep = "\\s+") %>%
  select(!c(1))
```

| pos | HLA | peptide | Core | Offset | I_pos | I_len | D_pos | D_len | iCore | Identity | 1-log50k(aff) | Affinity(nM) | %Rank | BindLevel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | HLA-B4402 | GSHDLGIILQK | GSHDLGIIL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | GSHDLGIIL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.015 | 42580.79 | 90.00 | NA |
| 1 | HLA-B4402 | SHDLGIILQKI | SLGIILQKI | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | SHDLGIILQKI | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.024 | 38731.55 | 65.00 | NA |
| 2 | HLA-B4402 | HDLGIILQKIR | HDLIILQKI | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | HDLGIILQKI | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.024 | 38400.24 | 65.00 | NA |
| 3 | HLA-B4402 | DLGIILQKIRD | DLGIILQKI | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | DLGIILQKI | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.011 | 44267.78 | 95.00 | NA |
| 4 | HLA-B4402 | LGIILQKIRDM | LGIILQRDM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 | LGIILQKIRDM | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.024 | 38411.46 | 65.00 | NA |
| 5 | HLA-B4402 | GIILQKIRDMP | GIILQIRDM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 1 | GIILQKIRDM | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.017 | 41463.75 | 80.00 | NA |
| 6 | HLA-B4402 | IILQKIRDMPY | IILQKIRDY | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 2 | IILQKIRDMPY | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.025 | 38152.18 | 65.00 | NA |
| 7 | HLA-B4402 | ILQKIRDMPYM | ILQKIRMPY | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 | ILQKIRDMPY | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.025 | 37993.98 | 60.00 | NA |
| 8 | HLA-B4402 | LQKIRDMPYMD | QKIRDMPYM | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | QKIRDMPYM | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.015 | 42595.54 | 90.00 | NA |
| 9 | HLA-B4402 | QKIRDMPYMDP | QKIRDMPYM | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | QKIRDMPYM | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.017 | 41645.82 | 85.00 | NA |
| 10 | HLA-B4402 | KIRDMPYMDPS | KDMPYMDPS | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | KIRDMPYMDPS | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.023 | 39039.53 | 70.00 | NA |
| 11 | HLA-B4402 | IRDMPYMDPSX | RDMPYMPSX | 1 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 | RDMPYMDPSX | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.036 | 33871.57 | 41.00 | NA |
| 0 | HLA-B4402 | PVTGYKVQYTS | TGYKVQYTS | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | TGYKVQYTS | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.011 | 44190.25 | 95.00 | NA |
| 1 | HLA-B4402 | VTGYKVQYTSL | VTGYQYTSL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2 | VTGYKVQYTSL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.020 | 40061.36 | 75.00 | NA |
| 2 | HLA-B4402 | TGYKVQYTSLT | TGYKVYTSL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 1 | TGYKVQYTSL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.020 | 40487.08 | 75.00 | NA |
| 3 | HLA-B4402 | GYKVQYTSLTG | YVQYTSLTG | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | YKVQYTSLTG | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.017 | 41521.20 | 80.00 | NA |
| 4 | HLA-B4402 | YKVQYTSLTGL | YQYTSLTGL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | YKVQYTSLTGL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.031 | 35710.76 | 49.00 | NA |
| 5 | HLA-B4402 | KVQYTSLTGLG | KVQYTSLTL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 1 | KVQYTSLTGL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.029 | 36392.20 | 55.00 | NA |
| 6 | HLA-B4402 | VQYTSLTGLGQ | VQYTSLTGL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | VQYTSLTGL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.016 | 42180.50 | 85.00 | NA |
| 7 | HLA-B4402 | QYTSLTGLGQP | QYTSLTGLG | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | QYTSLTGLG | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.011 | 44293.17 | 95.00 | NA |
| 8 | HLA-B4402 | YTSLTGLGQPL | YTSLLGQPL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2 | YTSLTGLGQPL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.034 | 34547.04 | 44.00 | NA |
| 9 | HLA-B4402 | TSLTGLGQPLP | SLTGLGQPL | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | SLTGLGQPL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.024 | 38475.10 | 65.00 | NA |
| 10 | HLA-B4402 | SLTGLGQPLPS | SLTGLGQPL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | SLTGLGQPL | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.026 | 37575.76 | 60.00 | NA |
| 11 | HLA-B4402 | LTGLGQPLPSX | LLGQPLPSX | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | LTGLGQPLPSX | NM_000094_3_COL | 0.014 | 42874.84 | 90.00 | NA |
| 0 | HLA-B4402 | FLRLLDLAQEE | RLLDLAQEE | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | RLLDLAQEE | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.014 | 42841.45 | 90.00 | NA |
| 1 | HLA-B4402 | LRLLDLAQEEL | RLLDLAQEL | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 1 | RLLDLAQEEL | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.029 | 36648.25 | 55.00 | NA |
| 2 | HLA-B4402 | RLLDLAQEELK | RLLDLAQEL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 1 | RLLDLAQEEL | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.029 | 36350.87 | 55.00 | NA |
| 3 | HLA-B4402 | LLDLAQEELKE | LLDLAQEEL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | LLDLAQEEL | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.013 | 43487.79 | 95.00 | NA |
| 4 | HLA-B4402 | LDLAQEELKEE | LDQEELKEE | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | LDLAQEELKEE | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.008 | 45629.40 | 99.00 | NA |
| 5 | HLA-B4402 | DLAQEELKEES | AQEELKEES | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | AQEELKEES | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.009 | 45287.57 | 99.00 | NA |
| 6 | HLA-B4402 | LAQEELKEESG | AEELKEESG | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | AQEELKEESG | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.013 | 43568.32 | 95.00 | NA |
| 7 | HLA-B4402 | AQEELKEESGF | AELKEESGF | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | AQEELKEESGF | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.231 | 4113.65 | 2.50 | NA |
| 8 | HLA-B4402 | QEELKEESGFL | QELKEESGF | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | QEELKEESGF | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.123 | 13202.71 | 6.00 | NA |
| 9 | HLA-B4402 | EELKEESGFLR | EELKEESGF | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | EELKEESGF | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.076 | 21904.46 | 13.00 | NA |
| 10 | HLA-B4402 | ELKEESGFLRE | ELKEESGFL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ELKEESGFL | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.030 | 36301.74 | 55.00 | NA |
| 11 | HLA-B4402 | LKEESGFLREX | KEESFLREX | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 | KEESGFLREX | NM_000106_5_CYP | 0.060 | 26205.35 | 19.00 | NA |

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
df_list <- lapply(file_names, read.table, skip = 6)
df <- do.call('rbind', df_list)
```

Then add your column names at the end.

Comment: Thanks, @Brian. It does not work, as each file is composed by many tables (identical headers) with text between them.